# Games launched from Steam in Ubuntu are grouped with the other Steam windows

Tags: games, steam, window, dock

When I launch a game with Steam the game window is automatically grouped with the other Steam windows. I'd like the game windows to have they're own icon in the pager and dock, seperate from the Steam. Is this possible, given that I like windows to be grouped in most applications?