# How can I prevent the Ubuntu launcher from stacking Steam with the games it launches?

Tags: launcher, steam

When I launch a game from Steam it stacks the game together with Steam in the launcher. Is there any way to disable this so that each game is it's own icon at the root launcher level?

Comment: This seems like basically the same question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/528800/games-launched-from-steam-in-ubuntu-are-grouped-with-the-other-steam-windows

Comment: It's from two years ago and was never answered.